# Как увеличить длину строки в prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Я ввожу вот такой код:

```
function btnClick2() {
                let sI = document.test2.item.selectedIndex;
                console.log(sI);
                let txt = "";
                txt =
                    "Запропоновано " +document.test2.item.length +" напоїв" +
                    "\nВибраний " +document.test2.item.options[sI].text +"(value=" +
                    document.test2.item.options[sI].value +",index=" +
                    document.test2.item.options[sI].index +")";
                if (document.test2.item.options[sI].defaultSelected) {
                    txt += "\nЦей напій вибирається за замовчуванням";
                }
                alert(txt);
```

и prettier его форматирует вот так:

```
function btnClick2() {
                let sI = document.test2.item.selectedIndex;
                console.log(sI);
                let txt = "";
                txt =
                    "Запропоновано " +
                    document.test2.item.length +
                    " напоїв" +
                    "\nВибраний " +
                    document.test2.item.options[sI].text +
                    "(value=" +
                    document.test2.item.options[sI].value +
                    ",index=" +
                    document.test2.item.options[sI].index +
                    ")";
                if (document.test2.item.options[sI].defaultSelected) {
                    txt += "\nЦей напій вибирається за замовчуванням";
                }
                alert(txt);
```

Как сделать чтобы он форматировал на большую длину строки,то есть как я написал в первом случае?

Answer (score 0):

для увеличения размера строки вам нужно либо создать файл `.prettierrc.json` и внутри указать `"printWidth": (число)` (чем больше число, тем больше будет максимальный размер строки), либо в настройке расширений найти `prettier`, где можно будет напрямую изменить значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]